# Выполнение php скрипта без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте.
Есть php-скрипт.

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['name'])) {
$total_cost = 0;
$total_count = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION['price'] as $key => $out) {
    $total_cost = $total_cost + (int)$_SESSION['price'][$key] * (int)$_SESSION['count_prdct'][$key];

}
foreach ($_SESSION['count_prdct'] as $key => $out) {

    $total_count = $total_count + (int)$_SESSION['count_prdct'][$key];
}
$cart_alert = 'количество товара ' . (STRING)$total_count . ' на сумму ' . (STRING)$total_cost;
echo $cart_alert;
}
echo 'asjdaoijsdaoisjdoaijsdaoidjs';
```

Есть div на странице.

```
<div id="cart">  
<a  href="http://dev.1-11.ru/forma/cart.php"><font color="#FF0000">Корзина {$cart_alert}</font></a>  
</div>
```

Как с помощью jquery/ajax обновить содержимое этого div, без перезагрузки страницы, выводом выхлопом php-скрипта.
Пробовал так

```
$("#cart").load("/cart_update.php #cart");
```

Но данная команда лишь делает div пустым.

Comment: что за адрес у вас такой? `#cart` зачем добавили?

Comment: Я отсюда брал  http://www.maxua.com.ua/blog/php-skript/jquery-job/reload-div.html - /cart_update.php- относительный путь. Пробовал и абсолютный вставить.

Comment: дак вы и оставьте только `$("#cart").load('/cart_update.php')` и посмотрите что вам сервер возвращает, в `Network` вкладке. Вам же надо просто записать в блок данные

Comment: А то вы пытаетесь в возвращаемом результате найти блок `#cart` и вставить его в ваш блок

Comment: О, спасибо большое - заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого надо использовать AJAX - запросы.

Код, который я использую для этих целей:

```
function send_request(r_method, r_path, r_args, r_handler)
{
    var Request = false;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        Request=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        try
        {
            Request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        };
        catch(CatchException)
        {
            Request=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    if(!Request)
    {
        return;
    }
    Request.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(Request.readyState==4)
            if(Request.status==200)
                r_handler(Request.responseText);
        if(r_method.toLowerCase() =="get"&&r_args.length>0)
            r_path+="?"+r_args;
        Request.open(r_method,r_path,true);
        if(r_method.toLowerCase()=="post")
        {
            Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
            Request.send(r_args)
        }
        else
        {
            Request.send(null)
        }
    }
}
```

Коротко об аргументах:

```
send_request("Тип запроса. get либо post","Путь/к/файлу.php","Аргументы. Например: topic=46764&page=4",function(response){
    //Код, который будет исполняться при успешном окончании запроса
    //response - переменная, содержащая ответ      
})
```

Небольшой пример:

test.html

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function send_request(r_method, r_path, r_args, r_handler)
    {
        var Request = false;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            Request=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        {
            try
            {
                Request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            }catch(CatchException)
            {
                Request=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }
        if(!Request)
        {
            return;
        }
        Request.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(Request.readyState==4)
                if(Request.status==200)
                    r_handler(Request.responseText);
            if(r_method.toLowerCase() =="get"&&r_args.length>0)
                r_path+="?"+r_args;
            Request.open(r_method,r_path,true);
            if(r_method.toLowerCase()=="post")
            {
                Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
                Request.send(r_args)
            }
            else
            {
                Request.send(null)
            }
        }
    }
    function request() {
      send_request("GET", "test.php", "testval=test", function(response) {
          document.body.innerHTML+=response
      })
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="request()">Загрузить!</button>
</body>

</html>
```

test.php

```
<?PHP
echo "Тестовая переменная: ".$_GET['testvar'];
?>
```

Comment: зачем использовать самодельный велосипед. если автор уже использует jquery?

Comment: Я бы не стал использовать jquery. Очень уж это раздутый фреймворк.

Comment: это библиотека, и теперь можно собирать части которые нужны. В любом случае, если в проекте **уже** используется jquery, добавлять в него самописный запрос, вместо использования готового - не всегда правильно, и в большинстве случаев неудобно.

Comment: @grundy, Кому как больше нравится. Я обычно не использую